# splitting the email id before @ if the entered email is correct other wise displaying error to enter correct email

Tags: c#, asp.net

It is a web application i have login it some fields like name,email id,login name like that but i need to split the email id @ before text it will display automatically in login name text box . when i entered email id split and display another name another text box like this:
i want to display like this

```
email id: xyz@gmail.com
login name: xyz
```

but if the given mail id is in this way

```
email id: xyz
```

then the text should not be entered into login name instead it should display incorrect email id.
i had tried this code it works fine in splitting but along with this i need to stop the text entered into login name if the format is not correct

```
String str = txtemailid.Text;
String[] name = str.Split('@');
txtloginname.Text = name[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a condition to set the txtloginname.Text only if de result of the split has two strings, the id and the domain after @.

```
txtloginname.Text = name.Length == 2 ? name[0] : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   try
            {
                String str = txtemailid.Text;
                String[] name = str.Split('@');

                if (name.Count() == 2)
                {
                    llbMsg.Text = "Entered Email" + name[0].ToString() + "Incorrect";
                }
                else
                {
                    llbMsg.Text = "Entered Email" + name[0].ToString() + "Correct";
                }

            }
            catch { }
```

Comment: validate email id and also enter before '@' name to another text box  and stop entering if email id is not correct formattingif email id: xyz@gmail.com.   spliting before'@' and displaying the text before '@'. login name: xyz otherwise using validator to tell the user to enter to valid email. can you please tell me  another way.